# SQL Join Query with Character Length

Tags: sql, ms-access

Help!  I'm getting errors in the following query...

```
SELECT * FROM PARTFILES INNER JOIN PRODCODE ON PRODCODE.PRODCODE = PARTFILES.PARTNO WHERE (PRODCODE.PRODCODE = "SERVICE") AND (PARTFILES.PARTNO LENGTH(PARTFILES.PARTNO)<10 ) ORDER BY PARTFILES.PARTNO ;
```

I'm totally green on SQL, but I know the jist of my problem is in this area:

```
...(PARTFILES.PARTNO LENGTH(PARTFILES.PARTNO)<10 )...
```

Basically, I want all the parts from the PARTFILES table that have a PROD.CODE of "SERVICE", but I **ONLY** want those that are less then 10 characters long.

Right now I'm getting:

> DAO OpenRecordset Error
>
> Error #3705 (Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression...

P.S. - Please don't judge, lol... I'm really new to this :-)

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_len.asp

Answer (score 0):

should be using LEN and proper coding on the condition

```
LEN(PARTFILES.PARTNO)<10
```

full query below

```
SELECT * 
FROM PARTFILES 
INNER JOIN PRODCODE ON
     PRODCODE.PRODCODE = PARTFILES.PARTNO 
 WHERE PRODCODE.PRODCODE = 'SERVICE' 
 AND LEN(PARTFILES.PARTNO)<10  
 ORDER BY PARTFILES.PARTNO
```

Comment: Okay, that prevented my error, but returns no results... now I'm concerned that my JOIN isn't right.

Comment: And that is a different issue

Comment: Reading the code you are joining by part no and prod code? Presumably the same data?